# Rxjava User-Retry observable with .cache operator?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

i've an observable that I create with the following code.

```java
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<ReturnType>() {

      @Override
      public void call(Subscriber<? super ReturnType> subscriber) {
        try {
          if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(performRequest());
          }
          subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          subscriber.onError(e);
        }
      }
    });
```

`performRequest()` will perform a long running task as you might expect.

Now, since i might be launching the **same** Observable twice or more in a very short amount of time, I decided to write such transformer:

```java
  protected Observable.Transformer<ReturnType, ReturnType> attachToRunningTaskIfAvailable() {
    return origObservable -> {
      synchronized (mapOfRunningTasks) {
        // If not in maps
        if ( ! mapOfRunningTasks.containsKey(getCacheKey()) ) {
          Timber.d("Cache miss for %s", getCacheKey());
          mapOfRunningTasks.put(
              getCacheKey(),
              origObservable
                  .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                    Timber.d("Removed from tasks %s", getCacheKey());
                    synchronized (mapOfRunningTasks) {
                      mapOfRunningTasks.remove(getCacheKey());
                    }
                  })
                  .cache()
          );
        } else {
          Timber.d("Cache Hit for %s", getCacheKey());
        }
        return mapOfRunningTasks.get(getCacheKey());
      }
    };
  }
```

Which basically puts the original `.cache` observable in a `HashMap<String, Observable>`.

This basically disallows multiple requests with the same `getCacheKey()` (Example `login`) to call `performRequest()` in parallel. Instead, if a second `login` request arrives while another is in progress, the second request observable gets "discarded" and the already-running will be used instead. => All the calls to `onNext` are going to be `cached` and sent to both subscribers actually hitting my backend only once.

**Now**, suppouse this code:

```java
// Observable loginTask
public void doLogin(Observable<UserInfo> loginTask) {
    loginTask.subscribe(
      (userInfo) -> {},
      (throwable) -> {
        if (userWantsToRetry()) {
            doLogin(loinTask);
        } 
      }
    );
}
```

Where loginTask was composed with the previous transformer. Well, when an error occurs (might be connectivity) and the `userWantsToRetry()` then i'll basically re-call the method with the same observable. Unfortunately that has been cached and I'll receive the same error without hitting `performRequest()` again since the sequence gets replayed.

Is there a way I could have both the "same requests grouping" behavior that the transformer provides me AND the retry button?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot going on and it's hard to put it into direct terms. I can make a couple recommendations though. Firstly your `Observable.create` can be simplified by using an `Observable.defer(Func0<Observable<T>>)`. This will run the func every time a new subscriber is subscribed and catch and channel any exceptions to the subscriber's onError.

```java
Observable.defer(() -> {
    return Observable.just(performRequest());
});
```

Next, you can use `observable.repeatWhen(Func1<Observable<Void>, Observable<?>>)` to decide when you want to retry. Repeat operators will re-subscribe to the observable after an onComplete event. This particular overload will send an event to a subject when an onComplete event is received. The function you provide will receive this subject. Your function should call something like `takeWhile(predicate)` and onComplete when you do not want to retry again.

```java
Observable.just(1,2,3).flatMap((Integer num) -> {
    final AtomicInteger tryCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return Observable.just(num)
        .repeatWhen((Observable<? extends Void> notifications) -> 
            notifications.takeWhile((x) -> num == 2 && tryCount.incrementAndGet() != 3));
})
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1
2
2
2
3
```

The above example shows that retries are aloud when the event is not 2 and up to a max of 22 retries. If you switch to a `repeatWhen` then the flatMap would contain your decision as to use a cached observable or the realWork observable. Hope this helps!